# Add "newline" character in localizable.strings

Tags: xcode, localizable.strings

How to add a newline character in `localizable.strings`?

I tried putting `\n`, but no success.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using `\n` should just work. With this line in "Localizable.strings":

```
"abc" = "foo\nbar";
```

and this code:

```
NSString *s = NSLocalizedString(@"abc", NULL);
NSLog(@"%@", s);
```

I get the output

```
2013-05-02 14:14:45.931 test[4088:c07] foo
bar
```

Comment: I agree. True: key shouldn't include `\n` - and why would anyone want it there... everything else (`\n` in localized strings) should work just fine.

Comment: Adding \n works if you display the text in the UITextView, or UILabel.

Comment: I had enables HTML therefore, \n wasn't working. anyways after putting html tags its working absolutely fine! any idea how to add links?

Answer (score 20):

Just adding newlines in the .strings file also works

```
"str" = "Hi ,

this is .

in a new line,

";
```

Comment: Am I missing something here? Xcode tells me that this is invalid. It only accepts the \n syntax..

Comment: It is very ugly and hard to maintain\

Answer (score 3):

This works in an UILabel and UITextview as long as you set the appropriate line number:

```
testLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

You could also set this to 0 which is automatic line count, also you should ensure that your label is big enough to show multiple lines, or else it will be cut off.

Answer (score 1):

this will not work in localizable.strings you have to create two keys and then only you can manage \n between two localizable strings during the concatination of strings.

Comment: This one helped me.! By creating 2 keys. `"someLocalised1" = "Some Localised 1";` & `"someLocalised2" = "Some Localised 2";` I wonder for few other strings it is working with \n. God knows Apple is cooking inside Xcode.